# repeat region inside php mail

Tags: php, email

I use a simple section of php in my header to send the contents of a mysqli query (in this case a combination of three queries - 'ORDER' has the shipping details, 'CUSTOMER' contains the email details of the customer, and 'PRODLIST' has a list of products entered into the shopping cart)

I put together the following script, trying to collect the 'ORDER' details, and add a repeating region to add all the records in the 'PRODLIST' query.

It didn't work, and I was wondering if this is even possible, and if not is there a solution that will allow me to send a simple html email with the full details?

Both queries are working by the way, they are listed on screen in the actual web page, but the mail code is not responding, and causing the page not to load.

```
$to = 'RECIPIENT REMOVED';

$subject = "order from  " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("CUSTOMER_NAME");

$headers = "From: " . $CUSTOMER->getColumnVal("EMAIL") . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $CUSTOMER->getColumnVal("EMAIL") . "\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: info@sigwebdesign.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";$from = "<".$CUSTOMER->getColumnVal("EMAIL").">";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>The following order has been received</p>';
$message .= "Delivery Type: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("DELIVERY_TYPE") . "<br>";
$message .= "<b>Delivery Date: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("DELIVERY_DATE") . "<br><br><br></b>";
$message .= "Company: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("CUSTOMER_NAME") . "<br>";
$message .= "Contact: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("PLACED_BY") . "<br><br>";
$message .= "Address: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("DELIVERY_ADDRESS") . "<br>";
$message .= "Address: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("CITY") . "<br>";
$message .= "Address: " . $ORDER->getColumnVal("STATE") . "<br>";
$message .= "Address: " . $$ORDER->getColumnVal("ZIP") . "<br><br><br>";

while(!$PRODLIST->atEnd()) {
$message .= "ITEM: " . $PRODLIST->getColumnVal("GENUS")." ".$PRODLIST->getColumnVal("VARIETY") . "<br>";
$message .= "QTY: " . $PRODLIST->getColumnVal("QUANTITY") . "<br>";
$PRODLIST->moveNext();
}
$PRODLIST->moveFirst();

$message .= "Total Cost: " . $_SESSION['fullcost'] . "<br><br><br>";
$message .= "This price does not include shipping, and applicable taxes. <br> Your order will be processed, and a final confirmation will be sent to you by email or by phone. <br><br>";

$message .= '</html></body>';


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Where are you using `$from`?

Comment: I don't have $from separated, it is part of the $headers

Comment: I can see that you had solved your problem. And I can clearly see that you have `$from` in your code!

Answer (score 0):

So I worked it out. I added an extra "$" in the coding, and it threw a whole big spanner in the works.

so the answer (note to self at least) is check check and triple check the code!